# Outlook alerts user when an email contains certain words before sending email

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, rules

I would like to be alerted before I send an email if the email I am composing contains a certain phrase.

Example: Hi (Client Name),

I would like to be alerted if I forgot to change "(Client Name)".

A similar situation is when you use the word attached in GMail, the client will alert you if you haven't actually attached a file.

Comment: Not that it really maters, but Outlook (2013 at least) also does the same thing when it detects a variation of the word "attach". :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can easily achieve the desired result with the following VBA macro:

```vb
Public Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    On Error Resume Next
    If InStr(Item.Body, "(Client Name)") Then
        If MsgBox("Are you sure to send this message?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Message Text Warning") = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```